# Trying to get libxml++ installed on OS X 10.6

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, libxml2

I am new to C++ and am trying to install the C++ bindings for libxml2.

After being at this for about four hours now, I feel like a joke is being played on me. I ran the configure script of lixml++ and it says I need packages libxml-2.0 >= 2.7.3 glibmm-2.4 >= 2.32.0

So I went to get glibmm2.4 and ran configure script. It says I need packages: sigc++-2.0 >= 2.2.10 glib-2.0 >= 2.34.0 gobject-2.0 >= 2.34.0 gmodule-2.0 >= 2.34.0)

So I went to get package sigc++ and ran the configure script and it says I need glib-2.6. I downloaded glib-2.6 and ran configure and it says I need libffi.

I think you get the idea.

I went through about four more versions of this and running into errors along the way. Now I am really close to giving up. I must be missing something.

While installing packages is thrilling, I don't really want to spend all day doing this just to simply use the libxml++ library.

Please tell me there is a better solution than chain upon chain of dependencies?

Comment: install either [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) or [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) and install via that mechanism, otherwise you'll be following dependencies until the cows come home.

Comment: also see this question - [http://superuser.com/questions/92872/apple-mac-os-x-is-there-a-package-manager-like-linux](http://superuser.com/questions/92872/apple-mac-os-x-is-there-a-package-manager-like-linux)

Answer (score 1):

For `libxml++` installation on mac, as per the documentation, you need to install `libxml2` and `glibmm2.4`. Refer to the [libxml++ website](http://libxmlplusplus.sourceforge.net/).

1. Install `homebrew`. If you don't have it already, refer to the [homebrew's website](https://brew.sh/).
2. Run `brew install libxml2`.
3. Run `brew install glibmm`.
4. Run `brew info libxml++`.